# Method inside a for loop gets called only once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I think I'm missing something pretty basic but I'll risk it anyway :).
I'm using a for loop to load different htmls into a `UIWebView`. When the html finishes loading I want to do some irrelevant stuff to it and move on. For some reason `webViewDidFinishLoad` is only called once at the end of the process of the for loop, even if I have 20 objects in the htmlArray and I'm trying to figure out way.

Any creative way to solve it?

Thanks

```
    for(int i=0;i<[_htmlArray count];i++)
        {
            msg = [_htmlArray objectAtIndex:i];
            [_tempWebView loadHTMLString:msg baseURL:nil];
        }
}
```

...

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [self doSomeStuff:webView]; // <--only called once

    NSLog(@"didFinish Snip Snap: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
          (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
}
```

Comment: are u sure _html.count is 20?

Comment: yes. I'm NSLoging every single one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that what's happening is that by calling `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` multiple times, you are just overwriting what you're asking the `UIWebView` to do. So the last one wins and the delegate is only called once.

Of course `UIWebView` may be written to go off and load asynchronously on a separate thread (it does, in fact) but even then, you're doing it so quickly in a for-loop that the previous loads are cancelled before they get a chance to load and only the last one wins.

Answer (score 0):

If you call several loads at about the same time, the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` will likely not get called until the last one is done loading.  It is also likely that only the last one will even start loading.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop isn't waiting for the view to finish loading before it starts loading again, so most likely only the last call actually gets a chance to finish and call `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Make an instance variable called `count` and load the first page in the `viewDidLoad`.  In the `webViewDidFinishLoad` increment the instance variable.  When `count` reaches 20 you're done.

That way each page is loaded before the next is called.